# Why does my remote development on VS code opens the check remote option by itself?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

When I run my script in the debugger I get that the VS code integrated terminal changes by itself to "check remote". Why is it doing that and how do I stop it?

e.g. see image to understand what I mean:

[image]

This is really really annoying because then I cannot see the output of my script that I am debugging.

---

Cross-posted:

- Gitissue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2330
- Quora: https://qr.ae/TmRs2A

Comment: The cross-posted link to the related bug seems to be tracking the progress:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1760
No clear reason given yet.